# Can someone explain this tail + line to me?

Tags: shell-script, tail

I'm looking through some of the scripts that are on the servers and came across an 80MB shell script. Naturally curious I decided to look in there and came across this line:

```
tail +4802 $0 |
zcat - |
(cd $LANG_TMP &&
 tar -xf - loc/$LANGPRE$LANGPOST.po loc/poextract)  >>/dev/null 2>>/dev/null
```

Can someone give me a general gist of what this line is supposed to do? I've never seen a `tail +` command before, usually it's `tail -`.

Comment: Read the man page, it explains it there.

Comment: Probably your huge script is a [shar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar) like archive. Try `tail --help`  & read [tail(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a plus means start printing from the nth line from the beginning of the file.

so +4802 will print from line 4802 till the end.

`man tail` gives you a manual page.

Comment: Interesting but when I actually try running `tail +2` on a different file I get the following error: `tail: cannot open \`+2' for reading: No such file or directory`

Comment: It might be a function in your script, invoking `/usr/bin/tail`

Comment: well you have to give it a filename to read, or else it will assume stdin

Comment: The command I gave was `tail +2 testfile.txt` and got the error: `tail: cannot open \`+2' for reading: No such file or directory`. It does work with `tail -n +2 testfile.txt` though.

Comment: @jabbajac: Newer versions of the POSIX spec don't support the `+42` and `-42` arguments for `tail`; instead, you have to type `-n +42` or `-n -42`. You can enable the older syntax with `export _POSIX2_VERSION=199209`. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html